# Angular directive is not set to last caret

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have a directive to format a Number in text box while typing, please find the directive below.

```
angular.module('myApp').directive('shortfmt', function ($filter, $document) {
        'use strict';

        return {
            require: '?ngModel',
            link: function (scope, elem, attrs, ctrl) {
                if (!ctrl) {
                    return;
                }

                ctrl.$formatters.unshift(function () {
                    var formattedValue = $filter('shortNumberInput')(ctrl.$modelValue);
                    setCaretPosition(elem[0].attributes.id.value, formattedValue.length, formattedValue);
                    return $filter('shortNumberInput')(ctrl.$modelValue);
                });

                ctrl.$parsers.unshift(function (viewValue) {
                    var plainNumber = viewValue.replace(/[,\.]/g, ''),
                        b = $filter('shortNumberInput')(plainNumber).replace(/\B(?=(?:\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, ',');
                    elem.val(b);
                    setCaretPosition(elem[0].attributes.id.value, b.length, b);
                    var c = parseFloat(b.replace(/[,\.]/g, ''));
                    if (isNaN(c)) {
                        c = '';
                    }
                    return c;
                });
            }
        };
}
);
```

Code is working fine in all browsers except android chrome and safari. In these browsers cursor is not at the last index when parser added comma to value. it will ignore the comma and directed to one index before. if there is two comma it directed cursor to two index before. as per my analysis cursor move when returning c. Is there any possible way to solve this.